# Return success/failure and error message of transaction?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I need to have an update and insert wrapped into a transaction that will be called from an external web application.  I'm trying to get back a basic success/failure status when it is called along with an error message if it failed.

What I would like to do is something like the following, but it gives me the following errors:

> INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement
>
> "SQLCODE": invalid identifier

```
DECLARE STATUS VARCHAR2(128); 
    MESSAGE VARCHAR2(128);
BEGIN
    UPDATE MYTABLE
    SET COL1 = 400
    WHERE USERNAME = 'bigtunacan' AND pk = 12345;
      
    INSERT INTO MYTABLE (username, col1, col2)
            VALUES('bigtunacan', 400, 'foo');

    SELECT 'TRUE' AS STATUS, '' AS MSG FROM MYTABLE WHERE ROWNUM = 1;

    COMMIT;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
            ROLLBACK;
            SELECT 'FALSE' AS STATUS, SQLCODE || SQLERRM AS MSG FROM MYTABLE WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
END;
```

Comment: There are lots of questions about that fairly self-explanatory error message. But why not just let the caller see the exception (and decide whether to commit or to roll back) rather than trying to catch and handle the exception? (And why do success and failure both have 'true'?)

Comment: The both having "true" was a mistake as I was typing up a shorter faked example of my actual proc to illustrate what I'm trying to do.

The issue would be that when this set of instructions is run I want to ensure that it is always run as a transaction to maintain data integrity rather than leaving it in the hands of the caller.  At the same time, the caller needs to be aware of success or failure.

Comment: You could also just re-raise the exception (i.e. ad `raise;`) after rollback. Then the caller will still see the exception on error, and nothing on success...?

Comment: Also `sqlcode` is already included within `sqlerrm` so it doesn’t make sense to concatenate the two.

Comment: @AlexPoole thanks.  I took your approach of just re-raising the exception after rollback.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson thanks; I'm new to Oracle and was not aware of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any Select statement inside a PL/SQL code needs an INTO clause, except the ones called from or within a cursor. In your case, You do not need to invoke any Select statement, but just assign static string values ('TRUE','FALSE') or pseudocolumns independent from SQL such as `sqlcode` or `sqlerrm` to your already defined variables.

So, consider using :

```
DECLARE 
    STATUS  VARCHAR2(128) := 'TRUE';  
    MESSAGE VARCHAR2(128);
BEGIN
    UPDATE MYTABLE
    SET COL1 = 400
    WHERE USERNAME = 'bigtunacan' AND pk = 12345;

    INSERT INTO MYTABLE (username, col1, col2)
            VALUES('bigtunacan', 400, 'foo');

   -- SELECT 'TRUE' AS STATUS, '' AS MSG FROM MYTABLE WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
   -- completely remove this above row, STATUS is already initialized as TRUE
    COMMIT;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    ROLLBACK;
    STATUS := 'FALSE'; 
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20333,'Caution : An error was encountered - 
                                  '||SQLCODE||' -ERROR- '||SQLERRM);

END;
```

Answer (score 0):

A Commit/Rollback should not be ideally included inside a called procedure. From [**Tom Kyte's**](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1519405621318) own words:

> I wish PLSQL didn't support commit/rollback. I firmly believe transaction control MUST be done at the topmost, invoker level.

You should consider converting your anonymous block into a procedure and define the transaction control in the invoker's code.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure yourprocedure 
(      p_status  OUT VARCHAR2,
       p_message OUT VARCHAR2
       ) AS

BEGIN
  UPDATE mytable
    SET
     col1 = 400
      WHERE username = 'bigtunacan' AND pk = 12345;

INSERT INTO MYTABLE (username, col1, col2)
            VALUES('bigtunacan', 400, 'foo');

     p_status  := 'TRUE' ; 
     p_message := NULL;

EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
     p_status  := 'FALSE' ; 
     p_message := SQLERRM ;
END;
/
```

**Invocation** ( May be another block, procedure or application layer )

```
DECLARE
     l_status    VARCHAR2(20);
     l_message   VARCHAR2(400);
BEGIN
     yourprocedure(l_status,l_message);

     IF
          l_status = 'TRUE'
     THEN
          COMMIT;
     ELSE
          ROLLBACK;
     END IF;
END;
/
```

Only exception is if it's defined as an [*Autonomous*](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/autotransaction_pragma.htm#LNPLS01302) procedure (mostly used for logging purposes) where you are supposed to commit inside the procedure.